# CKEditor create Plugin with access to PHP variable and MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ckeditor

I'm trying to edit the default "link" plugin within CKEditor such that the plugin will display a selection of links that I have stored in a MySQL database.

I've essentially taken the code from the anchor selector portion of the plugin and copied it over to my "article" snippet.

The problem that I'm having is that I don't know how to specifically get the data from the php (which is a JSON array) into the javascript within the confines of the plugin as shown below.

The source:

```
setup: function (a) {
    this.clear(); //Clears the dropdown menu
    this.add("");
    var data; //Initialize the variable data where I want the JSON from PHP to go.
    //This is where I want to obtain the data and spit it out!!
    $.post("titles.php", function (result) {
        //A Data-handler function call here doesn't work?
        //data = result also won't work because of scope
        //Something has to happen here though...
    });
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        data[i]["title"] && this.add(data[i]["title"]); //Add each item to dropdown
    }
    a.article && this.setValue(a.article.name);
    (a = this.getDialog().getContentElement("info", "linkType")) && "email" == a.getValue() && this.focus()
}
```

Sidenote: This code *does* work if I hardcode the exact output from the PHP file to a variable.

I might be missing something as silly as a commonly known "best practice" in JS as JS is not my forte, so please let me know if I'm ignorant or stupid!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

header.php

```
 <script src="ckeditor.js"></script>
 <script>
      var Globalvars = {
          myvar: '<?php echo $myvar; ?>'
      }
 </script>
```

Now, you can use this myvar variable in your .js file as:

```
 alert(Globalvars.myvar);
```

Comment: The code I shared is only a snippet of a larger js file which is not capable of PHP execution as it is client-side. Maybe there is still some way to similarly find a workaround like that, though.

Comment: you can have the functionality in a js file and create some global namespace in the php file with minimal js code snippet. Later on in your js file, you can use that namespace.